# Rails: Saving Parent and Child simultaneously with nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have an Event model and a Packages model:

```
# event.rb
belongs_to :organization, optional: true
belongs_to :event_type, optional: true

has_many :packages

has_many :collaborations
has_many :messages, through: :collaborations
has_many :forms, through: :collaborations

# package.rb
belongs_to :event

has_many :package_collaborations
has_many :collaborations, through: :package_collaborations
```

I want the user to be able to create an Event and Packages at the same time with a nested form like this:

[image: [IMAGE]]

These are my two forms:

```
#_event_form.rb (simplified for easier reading)
<%= form_for(event) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

<% if f.object.new_record? %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :status, value: 'upcoming' %>
<% else %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :attendee_count %>
    <%= f.number_field :attendee_count, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :status %>
    <%= f.select :status, [['Upcoming','upcoming'],['Completed','completed']], {}, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

  <hr>

  <div class="form-group required">
    <%= f.label :started_at, 'Starts' %>
    <div class='input-group date form_datetime'>
      <% if event.started_at.present? %>
        <%= f.text_field :started_at, class: 'form-control', value: event.started_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p") %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group required">
    <%= f.label :ended_at, 'Ends' %>
    <div class='input-group date form_datetime'>
      <% if event.ended_at.present? %>
        <%= f.text_field :ended_at, class: 'form-control', value: event.ended_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p") %>
      <% end %>
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.hidden_field :platform_type, value: "a_platform" %>

  <hr>
  <%= render 'packages/package_form', event: @event %> # <--- Nested form here.

  <div class="actions" id="listen-for-hover">
    <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary', :id => "event-create-button"  %>
  </div>
<% end %>


#_package_form.rb
<%= form_for([@event, @package]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :kind, value: params[:kind] if f.object.new_record? %>

  <div class="form-group required">
    <%= f.label :Your_offer_?, "Your Offer?" %>
    <%= f.text_area :offering, class: 'form-control', :placeholder => "e.g. Your logo on stuff" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :notes %>
    <%= f.text_area :notes, class: 'form-control', :placeholder => "Notes here"  %>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary', id: 'package-submit-button', disabled: true %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Using the form this way results in this error:

```
Extracted source (around line #3):
1  <%# remoteFlag = false %>
2  <%# remoteFlag = true if @event.title == "dummy event" %>
3  <%= form_for([@event, @package]) do |f| %>
4    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
```

Obviously this is because @event hasn't been created yet so there isn't an ID for it. What would be the best way to make this nested form that is used to make new Event/Packages (new Objects with no ID) at the same time or Edit existing (Existing objects with IDs) ones by using the partial in another part of the app?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :package
```

to your Event model (in event.rb).  Then, in the 'new' method of your events controller, add

```
@package = @event.packages.build
```

In your form, you will need to use the fields_for method.  There is an excellent Railscast on this whole process here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 
If you're not familiar with Ryan Bates' Railscasts, I highly recommend you spend some time with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'build' method for creating an empty 'package' in your 'event'. There is an example on the [official RoR guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-second-model)

E.g.

```
<%= form_for([@event, @event.packages.build]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: I inputted the exact same line of code and I get the same exact error:

`No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"packages", :event_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:event_id]
`

Comment: The issue is the event itself hasn't been created yet and it is also IDless

Comment: @Antonio You didn't mention the error in the question. The error is a different issue. Make sure you are creating a new 'Event' on your Controller method with `Event.new` .I highly suggest the official RoR guide, as it is the exactly same scenario you try to implement.